# Pandas find multiple words from a list and assign Boolean value if found

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, text-mining

So, I have dataframe like this,

```
data = {
  "properties": ["FinancialOffice","Gas Station", "Office", "K-12 School", "Commercial, Office"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is my list,

```
proplist = ["Office","Other - Mall","Gym"]
```

what I am trying to do is using the list I am trying to find out which words exactly matches with the dataframe column and for each word from the dataframe I need to assign a Boolean true/false value or 0/1. It has to be a exact match.

Output like this,

```
properties         flag
FinancialOffice    FALSE
Gas Station        FALSE
Office             TRUE
K-12 School        FALSE
Commercial, Office TRUE
```

So, It returns TRUE for only "Office" because it is the exact match from the list. FinancialOffice is not because it is not in the list. Also, For the last one **Commercial, Office** it is TRUE because **Office** is found in the list even though **Commercial** not. So, even one of them is present it will be TRUE.

```
df["flag"] = df["properties"].isin(proplist)
```

Above code works fine to assign a boolean true/false but It returns **FALSE** for the last one(Commercial,Office) as it tries to find the exact match.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a crafted regex with word delimiter:

```
import re

regex = r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, proplist))
# '\\b(?:Office|Other\\ \\-\\ Mall|Gym)\\b'

df['flag'] = df['properties'].str.contains(regex, regex=True)
# for a case insensitive match add the case=False parameter
```

output:

```
           properties   flag
0     FinancialOffice  False
1         Gas Station  False
2              Office   True
3         K-12 School  False
4  Commercial, Office   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an external function to do the check, for example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"properties": ["FinancialOffice", "Gas Station", "Office", "K-12 School", "Commercial, Office"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
proplist = ["Office", "Other - Mall", "Gym"]

def check_present(cell):
    for word in (list(e.strip() for e in cell.split(','))):
        if word in proplist:
            return 'TRUE'
    return 'FALSE'

df['flag'] = df['properties'].apply(lambda x: check_present(x))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           properties   flag
0     FinancialOffice  FALSE
1         Gas Station  FALSE
2              Office   TRUE
3         K-12 School  FALSE
4  Commercial, Office   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` and `strip()` to convert each `properties` string of comma-delimited properties to a list of strings, then use the python `set` intersection operator `&` to test whether any of the properties match those in `proplist`:

```py
propset = set(proplist)
df['flag'] = (
    df.properties.str.split(',')
    .apply(lambda x: len({s.strip() for s in x} & propset) > 0))
```

Output:

```
           properties   flag
0     FinancialOffice  False
1         Gas Station  False
2              Office   True
3         K-12 School  False
4  Commercial, Office   True
```